# Extjs4 reload tab.panel data

Tags: javascript, extjs4, tabpanel

I have a tab panel (every tab contain a Form Panel) and I want when I move from tab to tab, the fields in the form panels gonna refresh to got the default values as I refresh the page all over again.
Something like store.load() to refresh stores.
This is my tab panel

```
Ads = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
,title              : 'My panel'
,header             : false
,iconCls            : 'icon-param'
,activeTab          : 0
,loadMask           : true
,layoutOnTabChange  : true
,collapsible        : false
,items              : [form1,form2,form3]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In you controller you can listen for tabChange event

```
 this.control({
            'panel': {
                tabchange: this.onTabChange
            }

        });
```

Inside onTabChange function you can check for form and set it default value

```
onTabChange: function(tabp, form){
        if(form.id=== "form1"){
           set default value
        }
  }
```